# pass "this" reference to function inside on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following piece of code. What is does is when use hover's over a link then it consoles `this`.

```
var Mod = function () {
    $('.link').hover(this.hover, this.out);
};

Mod.prototype = function () {
    var hover = function () {
        console.log(this);
    },

    out = function () {
        console.log(this);
    };

    return {
        hover: hover,
        out: out
    }
}();
```

In my above code `this` references to `$('.link')` element but I want to use this for current object. So to achieve this, I can modify constructor to following.

```
var Mod = function () {
    var self = this;
    $('.link').hover(function () {
        self.hover();
    }, function () {
        self.out();
    });
};
```

This works fine but the constructor looks messy now. Second way is to use jquery `$.proxy()` again this will make my constructor look messy.

My question is that **how can I pass `this` which references to current object to rest of the functions inside object while using the `jquery's hover function` as i am using it now in first example above?**

Comment: You're going to have to use one of these (or `.bind()`), because that's how it works. `this` is set by jQuery for event handlers, so if you want that to change, you have to do it manually. Of course, you could use `$(".link").on({ mouseenter: this.hover, mouseleave: this.out }, null, this);` and access `event.data`

Comment: Also note that `var Mod.prototype = function () {` is invalid

Comment: @Ian Why it is invalid?

Comment: You can't declare a property as a variable

Comment: And here's an example of what I mean with my other comments: http://jsfiddle.net/ad4P6/1/

Comment: @Ian My bad. Now I updated my post and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it like that:

```
var Mod = function () {
    $('.link').hover(this.listener('hover'), this.listener('out'));
};
Mod.prototype = function () {
    var hover = function () {
        console.log(this);
        this.otherMethod();
    },
    out = function () {
        console.log(this);
        this.otherMethod();
    },
    listener = function(func) {
        var self = this;
        return function() {
            self[func]();
        }
    },
    otherMethod = function() {
        console.log("That's a method of Mod.");
    };
    return {
        hover: hover,
        out: out,
        otherMethod: otherMethod,
        listener: listener
    }
}();
```

Just use a helper which returns a function. Your constructor is clean, but your prototype is not so :)

Comment: That looks great. You could probably remove `hover`, `out`, and `otherMethod` from the `return`ed Object, as `listener` is really the only thing that needs exposed

Comment: Using a string to point to a function doesn't help your IDE checking for syntactical errors.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit How is that any different from using `.data("mod")`? Except that it's better organized

Comment: @Ian I'm defiantly not promoting it, the code in the OP is the way to go. The IDE can help you with both: syntax and autocompletion. Seems that you like to open discussion.

Comment: I think that it's better because it's a pure javascript solution and doesn't involve jquery. Also you are using an object as a proxy, which makes the things complicated.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Ahh yes, I forgot about your answer's text `but this will make the code less readable and prone to error`. I understand about your IDE, but that wasn't my point. I just meant that it ends up being basically the same as your answer, but as you've pointed out, you don't promote it. And yes, I'd rather discuss things instead of just accepting what people say :)

Comment: @Ian you're holding the right spirit. For what it is worth, I've clarified this in my answer.

Comment: @KrasimirStefanovTsonev you definitely didn't read the first part of my answer :)

Comment: Actually I read it twice now. I don't agree with some of your points and that's why I added my answer. But anyways, it's always good to see some other opinion. That's what makes SO a great place.

Comment: @Krasimir Could you please elaborate this line `self[func]();`? what is `[]`? Can't we do it like this `this[func]()`? What is the purpose of `()`? Does `()` mean calling `func`?

Comment: Yep, *()* means calling of a function. If you use *this* instead of *self* you are referring another scope. I.e. the scope of the newly created closure. *self* actually points to *Mod.prototype*.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question looks perfect to me. You're calling `hover` and `out` in the correct context making `this` valid and pointing to the instance of `Mod` inside those functions.

`this` in a member function should always point to the instance of the object, so I would keep doing it that way even though you think it's a mess. A good IDE will be able to assist you or the team with both syntax and auto-completion, which I think is more important.

**Don't do this**

While you could assign `this` to a data-member of `.link` it will make the code less readable and prone to error:

```
var Mod = function () {
    $('.link').data("mod", this);
    $('.link').hover(this.hover, this.out);
};

Mod.prototype = function () {
    var hover = function () {
        console.log($(this).data("mod"));
    },

    out = function () {
        console.log($(this).data("mod"));
    };

    return {
        hover: hover,
        out: out
    }
}();
```

Side note: you could simplify prototype definition and just write it like this:

```
Mod.prototype.hover = function() {
}
Mod.prototype.out = function() {
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the way the prototype is written, so unless you have a reason

Comment: @Ian yes but it's a bit contradictory: the OP doesn't like the extra code in the constructor, but does add a lot of extra code to declare the prototype

Comment: There is no "a LOT of overhead" here. And I'm guessing they're leaving out code in the `prototype` definition, because it's a little superfluous with what they have. There's still nothing wrong with `.prototype = { method: function, method: function }` which is basically what they have. And the OP never mentioned anything about overhead

Comment: @ian: overhead wasn't the correct wording, updated my comment

Comment: @Ian since he's returning the same function names in the `return { }` as the original name, and he's not enclosing (closure) any value or state what is the point in declaring the prototype as an immediate function when an object would suffice?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Per your wording change, you're right. But like I said, the OP may have not included other code that may be shared and kept private from the global scope. Other than that, I see nothing wrong with it, or at least consolidating it into one `.prototype = { method, ... }` setting

Comment: @Yaw If you read my comments, I mentioned what the OP has is a little too much, and they could condense it into one `.prototype = { method... }`. My original comment was referring to the fact that it's okay to use `.prototype = { method... }` (which is what the OP **basically** has) instead of multiple `.prototype.method = func...`. And of course, the fact that the OP may have left some code out, which required the use of a closure

Comment: @Yaw If you look at the other answer posted, I think that's a good example. Although, as my comment on it mentions, the only method that needs exposed is the `listener` one. Anyways, the other functions should be accessible only within that context, so the closure is "necessary".